# How to get below format of nested dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have two dictionaries

One is nested dictionary -

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> Dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

And another is normal one –

```
Dictionary<string, string> ObjDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

In normal dictionary I have values like this

> {[DateTime_7_25_2013_12_26_11_PM_Table_2_1_Trade_2_1.xml, 0000000047510D9744C9A54EB11C0]}
>   {[DateTime_7_25_2013_12_26_11_PM_Table_2_1_Trade_2_2.xml, 0000000047510D9744C9A54EB11C0]}
>   {[DateTime_7_25_2013_12_26_11_PM_Table_2_2_Trade_3_1.xml, 0000000047510D9744C9A54EB11C1]}
>   {[DateTime_7_25_2013_12_26_11_PM_Table_2_2_Trade_3_2.xml, 0000000047510D9744C9A54EB11C1]}
>   {[DateTime_7_25_2013_12_26_11_PM_Table_2_2_Trade_3_3.xml, 0000000047510D9744C9A54EB11C2]}

Now I want the nested dictionary like this –

```
“Key0”  DateTime_7_25_2013_12_26_11_PM_Table_2_1_Trade_2_1.xml
        DateTime_7_25_2013_12_26_11_PM_Table_2_1_Trade_2_2.xml

“Key1”  DateTime_7_25_2013_12_26_11_PM_Table_2_2_Trade_3_1.xml
        DateTime_7_25_2013_12_26_11_PM_Table_2_2_Trade_3_2.xml

“Key2”  DateTime_7_25_2013_12_26_11_PM_Table_2_2_Trade_3_3.xml
```

All the keys of equal values of normal dictionary should belongs to one key of nested dictionary.

Please suggest.

Comment: You want to convert it from one dictionary to second?

Comment: I want the nested dictionary like above from normal dictionary having values pattern like above

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried but I cant post that code as I am not reaching any close to it

Comment: `"All the keys of equal values of normal dictionary should belongs to one key of nested dictionary."` By definition, a `Dictionary` can only contain one item with a particular key, so your requirement doesn't make sense...

Comment: I *think* OP is looking for [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534304.aspx).

Comment: This is nested dictionary ..nested with list..list can have multiple values.

Comment: user a *nested dictionary* is a dictionary within a dictionary , I think what you are looking for is a way to get the key and value from `dict2` as a `list<string>[2](wrong syntax)` with a key

Comment: If you don't want to use LINQ, maybe something along the lines of: `foreach (var kvp in normalDict) { if (!nestedDict.ContainsKey(kvp.key)) { nestedDict[kvp.Key] = new List<string>(); } nestedDict[kvp.Key].Add(kvp.Value); }` ... (or with kvp.Key and kvp.Value switched)

Answer (score 1):

```
ObjDict.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Value).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList())
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if I understand the question correctly:

Given you have an input dictionary where you want to group the items by the values in the dictionary and put them into a new dictionary where each key is one of the values from the original dictionary, and each value is a list of the keys with that value:

```
var items = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"C03", "C"},
    {"B01", "B"},
    {"A01", "A"},
    {"C02", "C"},
    {"A03", "A"},
    {"B03", "B"},
    {"B02", "B"},
    {"A02", "A"},
    {"C01", "C"}
};

var result = items.GroupBy(item => item.Value)
            .ToDictionary
            (
                g => g.Key, 
                g => g.Select(x => x.Key).ToList()
            );

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.Write("Values for key " + item.Key + ": ");

    foreach (var value in item.Value)
        Console.Write(value + " ");

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
Values for key C: C03 C02 C01
Values for key B: B01 B03 B02
Values for key A: A01 A03 A02
```

As you can see, this output is not ordered (it's in the same order as the input).

If you want to order both the keys in the dictionary, and the values in each list, you can do so like this:

```
var result = items.GroupBy(item => item.Value)
            .OrderBy(item => item.Key)
            .ToDictionary
            (
                g => g.Key, 
                g => g.Select(x => x.Key).OrderBy(x => x).ToList()
            );
```

This change produces this output:

```
Values for key A: A01 A02 A03
Values for key B: B01 B02 B03
Values for key C: C01 C02 C03
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use that:

```
  foreach (var item in ObjDict)
  {
    if (Dict.ContainsKey(item.Value))
    {
      var e = Dict[item.Value];
      e.Add(item.Key);
    }
    else
    {
      Dict.Add(item.Value, new List<string>() { item.Key });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could create your own Dictionary, MultiDictionary, 
in the Multipledictionary, maintain a private dictionary with key and List
when add the value, check if key has already exists, if exists, add to the list
and you can make it Generic

```
public class MultipleDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private IDictionary<TKey, IList<TValue>> _dict;

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return _dict.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_dict.ContainsKey(key))
                return _dict[key][0];

            return default(TValue);
        }
        set
        {
            if (_dict.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                IList<TValue> valList = _dict[key];
                valList.Add(value);
            }
            else
            {
                IList<TValue> list = new List<TValue>();
                list.Add(value);
                _dict.Add(key, list);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the idea, try implement the rest yourself

Answer (score 0):

A bit of pseudocode, so you can do some work on your own :P

step 1:

```
 make a hashTable or something which stores your ObjDict.Values and your Dict.Keys
```

( "0000000047510D9744C9A54EB11C0" -> "Key0" )

step2:

```
for each  ObjDict.Key
  if(Dict.contains(HashTable[thisKey])
   Take List from Dict and add the ObjDict.Value
  else
   Make new list, add ObjDict.Value
   Dict.Add(HashTable[thiskey], theList
```